# Getting error during creating a widget using Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I was trying to create a widget from a fresh installed of Orchad Src CMS. The site is running Ok but when I was on Widget page, getting error: **There are no widget layers defined. A layer will need to be added in order to add widgets to any part of the site.**

[image]

Then, I typed the Name of the widget and Layer Rule and when clicked on Save button then getting error T**he rule is not valid: There are currently no scripting engines enabled** The screenshot is the following:

[image]

I tried to enable couple of modules which I felt required. But still getting the same error and am unable to create a widget.

Is there any external scripting do i missing or do i need to import some external code block? I am not sure. Can you tell me what actually creating this issue like some module is missing or ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lightweight scripting feature should be the one you want.

[image]